# How to create a Numpy array from a large list of list- python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, pytables

I have a list of list with 1,200 rows and 500,000 columns. How do I convert it into a numpy array?

I've read the solutions on [Bypass "Array is too big" python error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314689/bypass-array-is-too-big-python-error) but they are not helping.

I tried to put them into a numpy array:

```
import random
import numpy as np
lol = [[random.uniform(0,1) for j in range(500000)] for i in range(1200)]
np.array(lol)
```

[Error]:

```
ValueError: array is too big.
```

Then i've tried `pandas`:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
lol = [[random.uniform(0,1) for j in range(500000)] for i in range(1200)]
pd.lib.to_object_array(lol).astype(float)
```

[Error]:

```
ValueError: array is too big.
```

I've also tried hdf5 as @askewchan suggested:

```
import h5py
filearray = h5py.File('project.data','w')
data = filearray.create_dataset('tocluster',(len(data),len(data[0])),dtype='f')
data[...] = data
```

[Error]:

```
    data[...] = data
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 367, in __setitem__
    val = numpy.asarray(val, order='C')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 455, in __array__
    arr = numpy.empty(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype if dtype is None else dtype)
ValueError: array is too big.
```

This post shows that I can store a huge numpy array in disk [Python: how to store a numpy multidimensional array in PyTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843062/python-how-to-store-a-numpy-multidimensional-array-in-pytables). But i can't even get my list of list into a numpy array =(

Comment: How is the list (of lists) currently stored? Is it on disk, or calculated in memory?

Comment: Calculated in memory.

Comment: Can't reproduce, even on a 32bit system you should not get "array is too big", since the array simply isn't too big. So what numpy version are you using? Can you reproduce it with `lol = [[0] * 500000] * 1200; a = np.array(lol)` (much more -memory- efficient for testing)?

Comment: Nvm. it simply *is* too large if you are using a 32bit numpy/python (forgot itemsize factor). You should upgrade, since you apparently can use a huge amount of RAM, the system can hardly really be 32bit?

Comment: You want a chunk-based approach if you can't fit all the data in memory (ie make a numpy array). Use hdf5 and do map-reduce style on chunks rather than reading it all in.

Comment: More succinctly does `np.zeros((500000, 1200))` work?

Comment: @tcaswell, nope, i get array is too big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using *something* (either OS or python) which is only 32bit, which is the source of the size limitation.  The solution is to upgrade to 64bit.

Comment: it seems like so, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756791/python-process-using-only-1-6-gb-ram-ubuntu-32-bit-in-numpy-array

Answer (score 4):

On a system with 32GB of RAM and 64-bit Python your code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
lol = [[random.uniform(0,1) for j in range(500000)] for i in range(1200)]
np.array(lol)
```

works just fine for me but it's probably not the best route to take. This is the kind of thing [PyTables](http://pytables.github.io/) was built for. Since you're dealing with homogeneous data you can use the Array class or, better yet, the [CArray class](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/homogenous_storage.html#the-carray-class) (which supports compression). This can be done as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tables as pt

# Create container
h5 = pt.open_file('myarray.h5', 'w')
filters = pt.Filters(complevel=6, complib='blosc')
carr = h5.create_carray('/', 'carray', atom=pt.Float32Atom(), shape=(1200, 500000), filters=filters)

# Fill the array
m, n = carr.shape
for j in xrange(m):
    carr[j,:] = np.random.randn(n) 

h5.close() # "myarray.h5" (~2.2 GB)

# Open file
h5 = pt.open_file('myarray.h5', 'r')
carr = h5.root.carray
# Display some numbers from array
print carr[973:975, :4]
print carr.dtype
```

If you `print carr.flavor` it will return `'numpy'`. You can use this `carr` in the same way you can use a NumPy array. The information is stored on disk but is still quite fast.

Answer (score 2):

With [h5py / hdf5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/):

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

lol = np.empty((1200, 5000)).tolist()

f = h5py.File('big.hdf5', 'w')
bd = f.create_dataset('big_dataset', (len(lol), len(lol[0])), dtype='f')
bd[...] = lol
```

Then, I believe you can access your big dataset `bd` as if it were an array, but it is stored and accessed from disk, not memory:

```
In [14]: bd[0, 1:10]
Out[14]:
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

And you can have several 'datasets' in the one file (multiple arrays).

```
abd = f.create_dataset('another_big_dataset', (len(lol), len(lol[0])), dtype='f')
abd[...] = lol
abd += 10
```

Then:

```
In [24]: abd[:3, :10]
Out[24]: 
array([[ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.]], dtype=float32)

In [25]: bd[:3, :10]
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

My computer can't handle your example, so I can't test this with an array your size but I hope it works!

Depending on what you want to do with your array, you might have more luck with [pytables](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/tutorials.html), which does a lot more than h5py.

See also:
[Python Numpy Very Large Matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1062629/1730674)
[exporting from/importing to numpy, scipy in SQLite and HDF5 formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891137/1730674)

Comment: too bad, it's still too big for numpy

Comment: I don't understand. This doesn't make a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried assigning a dtype? This works for me.

```
import random
import numpy as np
lol = [[random.uniform(0,1) for j in range(500000)] for i in range(1200)]
ar = np.array(lol, dtype=np.float64)
```

Another option is to use blaze. http://blaze.pydata.org/

```
import random
import blaze
lol = [[random.uniform(0,1) for j in range(500000)] for i in range(1200)]
ar = blaze.array(lol)
```

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Answer (score -2):

An alternative is the following:

```
lol = np.empty((1200,500000))
for i in range(lol.shape[0]):
    lol[i] = [random.uniform(0,1) for j in range(lol.shape[1])]
```

This is reasonably close to your initial form, I hope it can fit into your code. I cannot test with your numbers, as I don't have enough RAM to handle the array.